# Using JIT in llvm (ExecutionEngine create error) C++

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm trying to use public example of compiling and running function from llvm bitcode, but it doesn't work (I'm using the last version of llvm)

Here is my code

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4146)

#include <iostream>

#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/SectionMemoryManager.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/CompileUtils.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Scalar.h"
#include "llvm/Analysis/BasicAliasAnalysis.h"

using namespace llvm;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    InitializeNativeTarget();
    InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
    InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser();

    llvm::LLVMContext context;
    std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> m{ new llvm::Module {"test", context} };

    Constant* init_value = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), APInt(32, 12));

    GlobalVariable* bsp = new GlobalVariable(*m, Type::getInt32Ty(context), false, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, init_value, "bsp", 0/*, GlobalValue::GeneralDynamicTLSModel*/);
    llvm::FunctionType* funcType = llvm::FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), {}, false);
    llvm::Function* mainFunc = llvm::Function::Create(funcType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", m.get());

    llvm::BasicBlock* bb = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, "entrypoint", mainFunc);
    IRBuilder<> builder(bb);
    builder.CreateRet(builder.CreateLoad(bsp));

    std::string err;
    llvm::EngineBuilder EB(std::move(m));
    EB.setEngineKind(llvm::EngineKind::JIT).setErrorStr(&err);
    llvm::ExecutionEngine* EE = EB.create();
    if (!EE) {
        std::cerr << "unable to create a jitter: " << err << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
    EE->finalizeObject();

    const auto fa = (int(*)())EE->getFunctionAddress("main");

    printf("%d\n", fa());

    system("pause");
}
```

I can compile and build but this error appears at startup

```
unable to create a jitter: JIT has not been linked in.
```

I looked on the internet to find a solution to this problem, it was said that the file `MCJIT.h` needed to be included, but the code shows that it is included. And it also crash me on end of the function. Like i can use this code in the other function, but it will trigger a Visual Studio breakpoint at the exit of the function

EDIT:

I tried calling the LLVMLinkInMCJIT() function, this gave no result and I saw the following in my binary.

`00007FF7C0D1AA96 | FF15 FC961A00 | call qword ptr ds:[<&LLVMLinkInInterpreter>]`

LLVMLinkInInterpreter function code

`00007FF8BCB6EC30 | C2 0000 | ret 0x0`

Look like I need to rebuild my llvm-c.dll, I'll try it and tell you what happens